# Handle multiple stored procedure status at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am unsure if there is a way to handle for multiple return statuses

```
IF @Age NOT BETWEEN 22 and 65
    RETURN -101 -- Age Criteria not met
ELSE IF (SELECT mem_status FROM Member WHERE mem_nric=@MemberNRIC) <>'Active'
    RETURN -102 -- Member Status inelgible
ELSE IF @StartDate<dateadd(DAY, 1, getdate())
    RETURN -103 --Reservation date before next 24 hours
ELSE IF @StartDate>dateadd(DAY, 7, getdate())
    RETURN -104
ELSE IF DATEPART(HOUR,@StartDate)<7
    RETURN -105 --Booking before 7am
```

I want to know if there is way I can set these multiple returns to return all at once or something because it is kind of inefficient to check for one error and then return when there can be multiple errors, which would mean each error would only surface after the previous is corrected.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: *all at once or something* so what does that actually mean?

Comment: @jarlh I am using Microsoft SQL Management Studio

Comment: Do a UNION ALL, one SELECT for each return code.

Comment: @Stu I was wondering if it is possible to check for all of the else if statement before returning and maybe returning all the statuses that have been passed

Comment: A stored procedure can only `return` a single integer value, if that's a requirement you might need to look at a bitmask, or just write a query to return a *set* of data. A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help.

Comment: If you are using return codes, then you can only use one return code at a time, there is no support to return multiple return codes. Unfortunately that's your only option if you are locked into using return codes. Another option is to return custom error messages. You can return multiple error messages and then exit your stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are stuck using return codes due to a requirements limitation, then this answer will not help you in returning multiple errors.

As stated in the comments discussion, a stored procedure cannot return multiple return codes, it can only return a single integer.

Here's a reference to the documentation on the subject:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15#returning-data-using-a-return-code

---

However, what you can do, is return multiple error messages, and you can return a bad return code if any errors have been detected. There is likely a cleaner way to do this, but this is one way it could be done:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_StackOverflow_Answer (
    @Age tinyint,
    @StartDate datetime,
    @MemberNRIC int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @errorStatus bit = 0;

    IF (@Age NOT BETWEEN 22 and 65)
    BEGIN;
        RAISERROR('Age Criteria not met',16,1) WITH NOWAIT;
        SET @errorStatus = 1;
    END;

    IF ((SELECT mem_status FROM Member WHERE mem_nric = @MemberNRIC) <> 'Active')
    BEGIN;
        RAISERROR('Member Status inelgible',16,1) WITH NOWAIT;
        SET @errorStatus = 1;
    END;

    IF (@StartDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE()))
    BEGIN;
        RAISERROR('Reservation date before next 24 hours',16,1) WITH NOWAIT;
        SET @errorStatus = 1;
    END;

    IF (@StartDate > DATEADD(DAY, 7, GETDATE()))
    BEGIN;
        RAISERROR('Reservation date more than 7 days in future',16,1) WITH NOWAIT;
        SET @errorStatus = 1;
    END;

    IF (DATEPART(HOUR, @StartDate) < 7)
    BEGIN;
        RAISERROR('Booking before 7am',16,1) WITH NOWAIT;
        SET @errorStatus = 1;
    END;

    IF (@errorStatus = 1)
    BEGIN;
        RETURN -1;
    END;
END;
GO

DECLARE @returnCode int;
EXEC @returnCode = dbo.usp_StackOverflow_Answer @Age = 21, @StartDate = '2021-11-30', @MemberNRIC = 0;
SELECT @returnCode;
```

Reasons for using `RAISERROR` in this scenario as opposed to other options:

- `PRINT` - does not return error codes only messages
- `TRY/CATCH` - will not work here because we want to collect multiple errors, and then return them all. In this instance we are using severity level 16, and anything that is 11+ will transfer execution to the `CATCH` block, which is not what we want.
- `THROW` - while this command does use the same severity level of 16, it does stop the execution of the stored procedure. So the issue is similar to using a `TRY/CATCH` block.